# HTTP response content is truncated when request is sent over WiFi

Tags: rest, http, heroku, networking, httpresponse

We're getting some HTTP responses with status 200 but with incomplete content (cut off at a different position in each request).

I wonder if there's something wrong with that network or if this kind of response errors must be expected and dealt by our application, i.e. if HTTP clients must check if the response content is complete. I haven't seen this behavior before.

More information:

The issue happens in a place where they have WiFi. If the client, the app, uses the mobile network, the response is always complete. We suspect that there's something wrong with that WiFi because we have not detected this issue in other places (other WiFis). The problem is not caused by the client since I could also reproduce it using Postman.

I made several tests at that place (using the app and also Postman) and found that on mobile data the response always comes OK, but when connecting to that WiFi the response sometimes gets truncated. Also, I saw that other API requests get the response correctly, even when the content length is 10 times bigger (I thought that maybe the response was too big, but we're talking about only 10Kb).

The failing request is a regular HTTP POST request using JSON and sent to our REST API made with Dropwizard and hosted on Heroku. The request gets processed correctly on the server, which returns status 200 and the content. The client gets the status 200 but the content is truncated, so the whole operation can't be finished successfully.